# How to save .pdf file using iText?

Tags: java, itext

I'm using **iText** to generate .pdf files and then save them to a specific location.

The problem is when running the service and I hit the service with a request, it saves the first file correctly but when I'm trying to generate another one, it generates a file with the data of the first one plus it appends the previous data with the new data. This happens for every request.

The code is given below :

```
    String reportName = Util.getReportname(headersArrayList);
    System.out.println("Report Name " + reportName);
    String file = Util.getProperty("save.report.file") + reportName;
    PdfWriter instance = null;
    try {
        Document document= new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        instance = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.open();
        addTitlePage(document, headersArrayList);
        System.out.println("request.getTables().size() : " + request.getTables().size());
        TemplateUtility.addMetaData(document, headersArrayList);
        createTable(document, request.getTables());
        document.close();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: how are you using this function? in a for-loop? and what is `addTitlePage` and `createTable`? [mcve]

Comment: its a method i created to add page title

Comment: Well, until you show me all the code, i cannot help you...

Comment: You could delete any existing file. But having one single file name for several service requests cannot be right.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this for "instance = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));"
 `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("yourfilename.pdf"));`